# Вывод имени пользователя в переписке

Tags: mysqli, php

Вопрос такой - есть страница на которой выводится переписка между 2 пользователями. Сообщения между мной и собеседником вывожу таким запросом

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *FROM `messages` WHERE `user_send`='$MY_ID' and `user_get`='$MY_FRIEND_ID' ");
```

, дальше вывожу значение поля text через while.

При таком запросе я получаю лишь сами сообщения между 2 конкретными пользователями, но как теперь вывести имена пользователей от которых пришло сообщение ?

Таблица users
id || login || password || avatar

Таблица messages
id || user_send || user_get || text

user_send и user_get - это id из таблицы users

Полный код вывода сообщений

```
<div id="messages" >
    <?
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT *FROM `messages` WHERE `user_send`='$MY_ID' and `user_get`='$MY_FRIEND_ID' ");
    while( $data = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
    $text = $data['text'];
    $user_send = $data['user_send'];
    $user_get = $data['user_get'];
    $date = $date['date'];
    ?>  
    <div class="msg">
        <div class="user"><img class="user_img" src="' тут должен быть путь к аватару '" /></div>
        <div class="info">
        <div class="name"><a href="#"> Тут должен быть логин пользователя, которому принадлежит сообщение </a></div>
        <div class="text"><?=$text;?></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <?}?>  
    </div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста доработать запрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `msg`.`id`, `msg`.`text`, `us`.`login`, `us`, `us`.`avatar` FROM `messages` as `msg`, `user` as `us` WHERE `user_send`='$MY_ID' and `user_get`='$MY_FRIEND_ID' AND `msg`.`user_send` = `us`.`id`
```

Соответственно поля доступные для отображения:

id - порядковый номер сообщения
text - текст сообщения
login - имя отправившего сообщения
avatar - ава отправителя

Попробуйте так - не получиться перепишу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, разобрался уже. Переписал этот запрос 

SELECT *FROM `messages` WHERE `user_send`='$MY_ID' and `user_get`='$MY_FRIEND_ID' 

на 

SELECT *FROM `messages` WHERE `user_send`='$MY_ID' AND `user_get`='$MY_FRIEND_ID' OR `user_send`='$MY_FRIEND_ID' AND `user_get`='$MY_ID'

Comment: А что изменилось? Вы ведь по прежнему не имеете доступ к полю со значением имени автора сообщения, ни так ли?